# is single table inheritance (STI) available when using polymorphism in mongoid?

Tags: polymorphism, mongoid, sti

When using STI and polymorphism in ActiveRecord, the following is needed to ensure that

```
:dependent => :destroy
```

will work properly:

```
def attachable_type=(sType)
    super(sType.to_s.classify.constantize.base_class.to_s)
end
```

Has anyone been using STI and polymorphism successfully with Mongoid?